# Errors building SSIS packages

Tags: sql, ssis, biml, visual-studio-2017-build-tools

SQL Server on a SSIS server has been upgraded to SQL 2017 from 2016

SSIS Packages are built in projects that Jenkins runs as a BIML Build (BIML Studio 2018) on a Build Server

Visual Studio Standalone has been upgraded as has the project deployment file

When we change the jenkins job to look for 2017 it thinks its looking for 2012. The environment variable in jenkins reflect what we see in the Windows PATH environment variable

When its run as 2016 the BIML Build runs fine, but the connections, script tasks, merge commands have script errors - see image link.

[Error Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I2Wkx.png)

The scripts are built in C# and used to build each component for SSIS.

We need to know what the likely cause of the errors in SSIS are.

Comment: This sounds like a job for BIML support.

Comment: Did u adjust the script task compatability to new version in BIML